# iOS 9 update now errors when I try to switch views

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios9

So I am switching a to a new view inside of a view like this

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

SKTransition *doors = [SKTransition fadeWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor] duration:.5];
GameScene *next = [[GameScene alloc]initWithSize:self.size];
next.highScore = self.highScore;

[self.view presentScene:next transition:doors];
self.timer.invalidate;

}
```

Xcode now gives me this error

> "CAEAGLLayer: 0x7b1acc80 : calling -display has no effect."

Any ideas of whats going on here?